# Reuse ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout

I use this kind of ViewGroup:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I must use 2 such layouts In my fragment, but with different icon and title. Is there some way to implement it without copy/paste and RecyclerView?

Comment: I think you should make it to custom view. Example create DataContentView extends LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to deal with it.

### 1. Use the include tag.

1.1. Move LinearLayout to a separate file.

1.2 Add layout using the include tag two times with different ids:

```
<LinearLayout ...>
    <include layout="@layout/your_layout" android:id="@+id/first" />
    <include layout="@layout/your_layout" android:id="@+id/second" />
</LinearLayout>
```

1.3 Set content programmatically:

```
View first = findViewById(R.id.first);
first.findViewById(R.id.date).setText("05/05/2020");
View second = findViewById(R.id.second);
second.findViewById(R.id.date).setText("04/04/2020");
```

### 2. Implement a custom view.

There are two ways also. The first is to inflate layout inside FrameLayout. The second is to extend LinearLayout and add content programmatically. I'll show you the first one.

```
public class YourCustomView extends FrameLayout {
    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        inflate(context, R.layout.your_custom_view_layout, this);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public void setContent(int iconRes, int titleRes, String data) {
        findViewById(R.id.icon).setDrawableRes(iconRes);
        findViewById(R.id.title).setDrawableRes(titleRes);
        findViewById(R.id.data).setText(data);
    }
}
```

### 3. Just copy-paste it :)

As I see icon and title are static and only data content changes, so it is not worth it to reuse such a simple layout, IMO.